# illegalStateException when using iterator.remove ()

Tags: java

I have a problem with iterator remove which is causing IllegalStateException. The error is occurring in

**depIterator.remove()**
I'm not sure why this is occurring. Any help would be appreciated.

```
List<Dependency> listofAllDependency = new ArrayList<Dependency>();

    while(!dependencyTable.isEmpty()){          
        //allValuesDependentsAreBuilt = false;
        Iterator<Entry<Dependency, List<Dependency>>> depIterator = dependencyTable.entrySet().iterator();

        while(depIterator.hasNext()){
            ArrayList<String> allValuesDependentsAreBuilt = new ArrayList<String>();

            Entry<Dependency, List<Dependency>> depEntry = depIterator.next();


            //If the key's values have no dependencies
            if(depEntry.getValue().size()==0){
                //System.out.println(depEntry.getKey());
                listofAllDependency.add(depEntry.getKey());
                dependencyTable.remove(depEntry); 
                depIterator.remove(); 
            }

            for(Dependency dep :depEntry.getValue()){

                if(!dependencyTable.containsKey(dep)){
                    allValuesDependentsAreBuilt.add("true"); 
                }else
                {
                    allValuesDependentsAreBuilt.add("false"); 
                }
            }

            if(!allValuesDependentsAreBuilt.contains("false")){ 

                listofAllDependency.add(depEntry.getKey());
                dependencyTable.remove(depEntry);
                depIterator.remove();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html remove() throws IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method

Comment: Thanks Martin! I completely forgot that if the removed is previously called it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems following line is culprit:

```
dependencyTable.remove(depEntry);
```

Don't  do add/remove on datastructure while iterating (which will cause `IllegalStateException`) .

Following should be enough:

```
  depIterator.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

When looping over a data structure and adding or removing contents of that datastructure at the same time, you can run into problems.  If you want to remove items from a list while iterating over the list I would recommend keeping track of what you want to remove and then removing it all after you are done looping.  Looking at your code specifically I would keep this line

```
dependencyTable.remove(depEntry);
```

and take out the line of code that modifies the iterator